# Error adding data to Elastic from FluentD

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I'm trying to pass data to Elastic via FluentD, which is running in a Kubernetes pod. Elastic is rejecting the data with the message

```
'Could not dynamically add mapping for field [app.kubernetes.io/instance]. Existing mapping for [kubernetes.labels.app] must be of type object but found [text].'
```

I've tried to resolve this using the rewrite_tag plugin but I couldn't get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

As the error message suggests you have an issue with the current mapping and the document you are trying to ingest.

It seems like the mapping expect somthing like:

```json
{
  "Kubernetes":{
    "labels":{
      "app":{...}
    }
  }
}
```

But the document you sent was in the following format:

```json
{
  "Kubernetes":{
    "labels":{
      "app": "some text"
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution

### 1. The mapping is correct

You will need to rename/move the text field in somewhere else, maybe in `kubernetes.labels.app.name`

### 2. The mapping is wrong

You will have to delete the index, an re create it with the right mapping.

Comment: Thanks, Paulo. How do I rename/move the text field?

Comment: How does the data goes from fluentdb to elasticsearch, do you use logstash ? filebeat ?

Comment: Straight from fluentd to elastic, using the @elasticsearch plugin. However I have managed to sort the problem out now: I'm using a record_transformer plugin to remove the keys which are causing the problem.